# Считывание данных из файла и занесение их в структуру

Tags: c++, строки, файлы, структуры, динамические-массивы

Задание: Считать данные из файла, занести их в структуру и вывести в консоль.

Структура данных в файле: `ABLEC&C,Missha,350.00,100,10.02.2017,South Korea;`

Не удается считать данные и занести их в динамический массив структур.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить?

Код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct Goods {
    char company[40];
    char name[40];
    char country[50];
    double price;
    int amount;
    struct {
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
    } date;
};

int main() {
    fstream file("goods.txt", ios::in);
    if (file.is_open()) {
        // находим количество записей о товарах в файле
        int records = 0;
        char stop;
        for (file >> stop; !file.eof(); file >> stop)
            if (stop == ';') records++;

        // считываем структуру в файле и выводим в консоль
        Goods* goods = new Goods[records];
        char* token;
        char line[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < records; i++) {
            cout << "Product " << i + 1 << endl;
            file.getline(line, 256, ';');
            token = strtok(line, ",");
            strcpy(goods[i].company, token);
            cout << "Company: " << goods[i].company << endl;
        }
    }
    else cerr << "Error with opening file." << endl;
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: Как вариант -- изучите [fscanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3p.html) и напишите подходящиую строку формата.

Comment: @user478629, в line - строка считывается ? Дебагом проверяли ?

Comment: после считывания количества данных, закройте и откройте файл. Потом опять считывайте уже данные. ; или просто вернитесь в начало с помощю `seek`

Answer (score 0):

После считывания количества данных, нужно закрыть и открыть файл заново. И снова считать данные или просто вернуться в начало с помощью `seek`.